# GPG error: http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: server, apt, gnupg

apt-get used to work until a couple of days ago.
Now I am banging my head on the wall with no avail.

This is the output from a Ubuntu server 14.04

`sudo apt-get update`

```
Get:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease [2,256 B]
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 2,256 B] [Waiting for headers]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InRelease into data and signature
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
E: GPG error: http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

`sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true`

```
0% [Working]GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: it.archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=2256-
If-Range: Sun, 19 Oct 2014 22:41:26 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect
Server: OpenRG
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://vodafone.station/?org_url=http://it.archive.ubuntu.com%2fubuntu%2fdists%2ftrusty%2fInRelease&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c&http_intercept_priority=400&intercept_id=5&u=KE9wZW5SRyBkYXRhCiAgKHN5c3RlbQogICAgKHZlcnNpb24oNS40LjguMS4xNjAuOC4yNCkpCiAgICAoaHcoQkNNOTYzNjJfVk9YXzEuNV9JVCkpCiAgICAoZGlzdChWT1hfMS41X0lUKSkKICAgIChybXRfbW5nKDEpKQogICkKICAoY3BlX2lkKFMxNDA3MDAwMDA1MTEzNikpCiAgKGRldihicjApKQopCg%3D%3D
Connection: close

GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: it.archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=2255-
If-Range: Sun, 19 Oct 2014 15:53:55 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com]GET /?org_url=http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c&http_intercept_priority=400&intercept_id=5&u=KE9wZW5SRyBkYXRhCiAgKHN5c3RlbQogICAgKHZlcnNpb24oNS40LjguMS4xNjAuOC4yNCkpCiAgICAoaHcoQkNNOTYzNjJfVk9YXzEuNV9JVCkpCiAgICAoZGlzdChWT1hfMS41X0lUKSkKICAgI
ChybXRfbW5nKDEpKQogICkKICAoY3BlX2lkKFMxNDA3MDAwMDA1MTEzNikpCiAgKGRldihicjApKQopCg== HTTP/1.1
Host: vodafone.station
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=2256-
If-Range: Sun, 19 Oct 2014 22:41:26 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)
```

`wget -O - http://it.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
    --2014-10-20 02:19:09--  http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/
    Resolving it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)... 193.206.140.45, 193.206.139.45,     2001:760:ffff:b0::45, ...
Connecting to it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)|193.206.140.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Redirect
Location: http://vodafone.station/?org_url=http://it.archive.ubuntu.com&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c&http_intercept_priority=400&intercept_id=5&u=KE9wZW5SRyBkYXRhCiAgKHN5c3RlbQogICAgKHZlcn
Npb24oNS40LjguMS4xNjAuOC4yNCkpCiAgICAoaHcoQkNNOTYzNjJfVk9YXzEuNV9JVCkpCiAgICAoZGlzdChWT1hfMS41X0lUKSkKICAgIChybXRfbW5nKDEpKQogICkKICAoY3BlX2lkKFMxNDA3MDAwMDA1MTEzNikpCiAgKGRldihicjApKQop
Cg%3D%3D [following]
--2014-10-20 02:19:09--  http://vodafone.station/?org_url=http://it.archive.ubuntu.com&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c&http_intercept_priority=400&intercept_id=5&u=KE9wZW5SRyBkYXRhCiAgKHN5c3R
lbQogICAgKHZlcnNpb24oNS40LjguMS4xNjAuOC4yNCkpCiAgICAoaHcoQkNNOTYzNjJfVk9YXzEuNV9JVCkpCiAgICAoZGlzdChWT1hfMS41X0lUKSkKICAgIChybXRfbW5nKDEpKQogICkKICAoY3BlX2lkKFMxNDA3MDAwMDA1MTEzNikpCiAgK
GRldihicjApKQopCg%3D%3D
Resolving vodafone.station (vodafone.station)... 192.168.0.1
Connecting to vodafone.station (vodafone.station)|192.168.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://vodafone.station/?page=dashboard_wizard.html&org_url=http%3a%2f%2fit%2earchive%2eubuntu%2ecom&intercept_id=5&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c [following]
--2014-10-20 02:19:09--  http://vodafone.station/?page=dashboard_wizard.html&org_url=http%3a%2f%2fit%2earchive%2eubuntu%2ecom&intercept_id=5&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c
Connecting to vodafone.station (vodafone.station)|192.168.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2256 (2.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

 0% [                                                                                                                             ] 0           --.-K/s              <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
 "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type='text/css' />
                <!--[if lt IE 7.]>
                   <script defer type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'  src='js/pngfix.js'></script>
                <![endif]-->
                <!--[if IE]>
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style_exp.css' type='text/css' />
                <![endif]-->
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/wizard.css' type='text/css' />

                <script language='JavaScript' src='jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='jquery/jquery.ba-bbq.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='jquery/jqSOAPClient.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script src='main.cgi?js=rg_config.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='Javascript' src='js/lang.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='Javascript' src='main.cgi?page=dm_path.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='js/utils.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='js/wizard_levels.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='js/sm.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='js/wizard_painter.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='js/wizard_states.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript' src='main.cgi?page=back_end.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
                <script language='JavaScript'>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            dashboard_init();
                        });
                </script>
        <script language='JavaScript'>var dm_cookie='1188021007';</script></head>
        <body>
                <div id="logo"><div id="menu"></div></div>
                <div id="main">
                        <div id="title"></div>
                        <div id="content"><div id="center"></div><hr/>
                                <noscript>
                                    <h1>Per visualizzare correttamente la pagina richiesta clicca su abilita. Abilita - Blocca</h1>
                                </noscript>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bottom"></div>
                        <div id="footer"></div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

As far as I can see it seems like my ISP is getting in the way.

Funny enough I have a laptop on the same LAN with Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, and that still works fine.

`wget -O - http://it.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
--2014-10-20 02:29:13--  http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/
Resolving it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)... 193.206.139.45, 193.206.140.45, 2001:760:ffff:b0::45, ...
Connecting to it.archive.ubuntu.com (it.archive.ubuntu.com)|193.206.139.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1502 (1,5K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              <html>
<head><title>Index of /</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="0/">0/</a>                                                 25-Nov-2008 11:12                   -
<a href="1/">1/</a>                                                 12-May-2014 06:13                   -
<a href="2/">2/</a>                                                 11-Aug-2014 09:56                   -
<a href="images/">images/</a>                                            12-Nov-2011 20:26                   -
<a href="mirrors/">mirrors/</a>                                           11-Aug-2014 09:57                   -
<a href="rainbow/">rainbow/</a>                                           16-Oct-2012 12:56                   -
<a href="ubuntu/">ubuntu/</a>                                            19-Oct-2014 22:27                   -
<a href="FOOTER.html">FOOTER.html</a>                                        12-Nov-2011 21:12                  40
<a href="HEADER.html">HEADER.html</a>                                        15-Nov-2011 16:35                2726
<a href="boomerang.js">boomerang.js</a>                                       12-Nov-2011 20:30               33210
<a href="favicon.ico">favicon.ico</a>                                        05-Dec-2008 12:02                2494
<a href="robots.txt">robots.txt</a>                                         18-Feb-2011 12:40                 111
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

ANY help or hints would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate. My network does **not** require authentication. Also from another pc on the same LAN I don't get the same response.

Comment: Clearly it has to do with your local network. As you can see, all HTTP request get redirected to http://vodafone.station/?page=dashboard_wizard.html (192.168.0.1). Whether its an authentication page or not, your network is requesting input from you.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. That is indeed what I thought myself. Though the laptop I have on the **same** LAN can hit the Ubuntu mirror straight. The only differences between the two machines are Server vs. Desktop, Static vs. DHCP and a few port forwards to the Server. None of these differences should explain the difference in behavior. This is well driving me mental..

Comment: Got this error from a bad mirror in the Ubuntu [mirror list](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt)  while using apt `mirror://` `sources.list` format (e.g.: `deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe mu
ltiverse`).    The problematic mirror was a domain no longer in service as a mirror:  http://mirror.veracruz.co/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have actually browsed to url `http://vodafone.station/?page=dashboard_wizard.html&org_url=http%3a%2f%2fit%2earchive%2eubuntu%2ecom&intercept_id=5&host_mac=00:21:9b:46:53:9c` and I was presented with a completely useless wizard page, inviting me to complete the installation (?!) and afterwards to download whatever mobile app. I clicked on **decline** at both steps and presto! I can finally hit the Ubuntu mirrors. Probably the router records whether that step has been completed by any machine on the LAN, and if so it stop showing up at all. I am not sure how I didn't have any problems with the Laptop which is on the same LAN. I browsed to that page with a Windows PC anyway, while I am using the Server via ssh. Hence the blocking page can't be IP specific.